# No default constructor exists for a class "Rectangle" on Rectangle class

Tags: c++

I have my problem on line 44 I don't understand why this happen and how to fix it
It say that  No default constructor exists for a class "Rectangle" I try to change but it same

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
private:
    double width;
    double height;
public:
    Rectangle(double width, double height);
    double area();
    double circumference();
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
};
class SquareRectangle:public Rectangle {
private:
    double side;
public:
    SquareRectangle(double side);
    double getSide();
};




Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double height){
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
double Rectangle::area(){
    return M_PI*pow(height,2);
}
double Rectangle::circumference(){
    return  2*(width+height);
}

SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side) {
       this->side  = side;
}
```

Comment: SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side) {
       this->side  = side;
} This line that my problem

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: change `SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side) {
       this->side  = side;
}` to `SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side) : Rectangle(side, side), side(side) {}`.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor for details about the syntax used.

Comment: SquareRectangle can't initialize the base class automatically b/c there is no default constructor(no-args) so you have to manually do it

Comment: Thankyou I got it now